# Comma Separated List as part of a SQL SELECT Results

Tags: sql

I would like to return a list of Employees, various information about them and a column with the list of the top 3 projects they have hours assigned to them each month in a comma separated list.  I have a select statement that returns the hours successfully, but I'm not sure how to embed it into a select statemnet.  Below is the select statement.  I am trying to do this in SQL Server.

```
        DECLARE @Projects varchar(max)
    SELECT Top(3) @Projects = COALESCE(@Projects+', ' ,'') + ltrim(rtrim(Projects.Title))
                FROM         EmployeeProjectPlanning INNER JOIN
                  Projects ON EmployeeProjectPlanning.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID
                WHERE     (EmployeeProjectPlanning.EmpID = 1) AND (EmployeeProjectPlanning.MonthID = 9) AND (EmployeeProjectPlanning.Year = 2011)
                ORDER BY EmployeeProjectPlanning.Hours DESC
    SELECT @Projects
```

Comment: Please, please, please tell us what SQL product you're using.  MySQL and SQLite would do this with GROUP_CONCAT, in SQL Server you need to write a scalar stored procedure to do it.

Comment: judging by the syntax, it's MS SQL. Also, I find it useful to make an aggregate CLR function for this purpose, to mimic MySQL's group_concat, if access rights permit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL 2005 or higher, you can use `FOR XML` to create the comma separated list in one field. Just put the following in your `SELECT` statement where you need the projects column:

```
SUBSTRING(
    (SELECT TOP (3) ','+ltrim(rtrim(Projects.Title)) 
     FROM  EmployeeProjectPlanning AS emp
     INNER JOIN Projects as proj ON emp.ProjectID = proj.ProjectID
     WHERE (emp.EmpID = 1)
        AND (emp.MonthID = 9)
        AND (emp.Year = 2011)
     ORDER BY emp.Hours DESC
    FOR XML PATH('')
),2,8000) AS Projects
```